# Sqlite for iOS - Accent (tilde) insensitive match in an fts table

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I enabled fts in sqlite for iphone and tried this and works, although very slow:

```
SELECT field FROM table_fts WHERE replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(field), 'á','a'),'é','e'),'í','i'),'ó','o'),'ú','u') LIKE replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower('%string%'), 'á','a'),'é','e'),'í','i'),'ó','o'),'ú','u')
```

But it does not work when I want to use MATCH, it does not bring me results and there is no error

```
SELECT field FROM table_fts WHERE replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower(field), 'á','a'),'é','e'),'í','i'),'ó','o'),'ú','u') MATCH replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(lower('string'), 'á','a'),'é','e'),'í','i'),'ó','o'),'ú','u')
```

Is there any error or is there any other approach where I can make a tilde insensitive search?. I looked answers in the web with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches:

First, you can violate normal-form and add columns to your table containing ASCII-only representation of your searchable fields. Furthermore, before doing a search against this secondary search column, you also remove international characters from the string that being searched for, too (that way you're looking for ASCII-only string in a field with the ASCII-only representation).

By the way, if you want a more general purpose conversion of international characters with ASCII, you can try something like:

```
- (NSString *)replaceInternationalCharactersIn:(NSString *)text
{    
    NSData *stringData = [text dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:stringData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Second, you could presumably use `sqlite3_create_function()` to write your own function (that presumably invokes a permutation of the above) that you can use right in your SQL statements themselves. See the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18).

**Update:**

By the way, given that you're doing FTS, the `sqlite3_create_function()` approach is probably not possible, but it strikes me that you could either do FTS on the field containing the ASCII-only string, or write your own [tokenizer](http://sqlite.org/fts3.html#tokenizer) that does something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks, I just thought about your first approach as the last option. I tried it and it works fine and fast.